# Let $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^n$ be convergent on $(-R,R),$ with $R>0.$ Prove that, if $f(x)=0$, $a_n=0$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, power-series, taylor-expansion

I'm stuck on a solution that our teacher gave to us. This is the exercise:

> Let $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^n$ be convergent on $(-R,R),$ with $R>0.$
>
> Suppose that $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in(-R,R)$ and prove that $a_n=0$ for all $n$.

My teachers' solution:

> $f(x)=0 \implies f^{n)}(0)=0$, so $a_n=\frac{f^{n)}(0)}{n!}=0 \implies a_n=0$ for all $n$.

I don't understand her solution. She's supposing that the given series is the taylor polynomial of $f(x)$, but I don't know why she can do it.

Any explanation or other way to prove this exercise will be really appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are given:
$$\begin{align}
f(x)&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^n\\
&=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3\cdots+a_ix^i+\cdots\\
\therefore f^1(x)&=a_1+2a_2x+3a_3x^2+\cdots+ia_ix^{i-1}+\cdots\\
\therefore f^2(x)&=2a_2x+3.2a_3x+\cdots+i(i-1)x^{i-2}+\cdots\\
\cdots\\
\therefore f^i(x)&=i(i-1)(i-2)\cdots3.2.1a_i+\cdots\\
\cdots\\
\end{align}$$
Evaluating these at $x=0$ gives us:
$$\begin{align}
f(0)&=a_0&&=0!a_0\\
f^1(0)&=a_1&&=1!a_1\\
f^2(0)&=2a_2x&&=2!a_2\\
\cdots\\
f^i(0)&=i(i-1)(i-2)\cdots3.2.1a_i&&=i!a_i\\
\cdots\\
\end{align}$$
Hopefully you can deduce the rest.

Answer (score 2):

A function defined by a (convergent) power series on an interval $(-R,R)$ satisfies the property that $a_n=\dfrac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}$.

Actually such a function is differentiable and
$$ f'(x)=\sum_{n\ge 1}n a_n x^{n-1},$$
hence it is $C^{\infty}$ and
$$ f^{(k)}(x) = \sum_{n\ge k}n(n-1)\dots (n-k+1)\mkern1mu a_n x^{n-k}. $$
Now set $k=n, x=0$, and you get
$$f^{(n)}(0)=n!\mkern2mu a_n.$$

*Note:*

This proves the series, truncated at order $n$ is indeed the *Taylor-Mac Laurin polynomial* of $f(x)$ of order $n$ explains why it is called the *Taylor series* of $f(x)$.

Comment: Oh yes! Thanks for pointing it. 'Tis corrected now.

Answer (score 0):

since $f(x)=0$ is a smooth function(which means any order derivative of it exists), it can be expanded as a taylor series. If a function can be expanded as a taylor series, then any power series in the form $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_{n} x^{n} $ is equal to its taylor series because of the uniqueness of taylor series. Hence, you can treat $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_{n} x^{n} $ as its taylor series.

Answer (score 0):

Ok consider 3 cases :

1)$(a_{n}x^{n})^{(i)} = 0 $ , for all $i<n$, because there is $x^{...} = 0 (x=0)$

2)$(a_{n}x^{n})^{(i)} = n!a_{n}$, $i=n$

3)and consider $i>n$, that's easier

So, $f^{(n)}(0) = n!a_{n}$